# Rails - not letting model be updated if fields have certain values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have my Ticket model. And I have two select fields in addition to others. Now, on my Create action i have this:

```
if @ticket.user_id != 0 && @ticket.team_id != 0
  flash[:alert] = "You cannot assign a ticket to both a team and a user!"
  render action: "new"
else
  .... *execute update code normally*
end
```

because i can't allow both of them to be different that 0, and this works well.

however I have the same line on my Update action, and it still allows for both fields to be different than 0.

Any ideas why? Or do you have another, better way of handling this?

Here is my Controller:

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def show
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @ticket }
    end
  end
  def new
    @ticket = Ticket.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @ticket }
    end
  end
  def edit
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
    @ticket.content = nil
    @ticket.whodidit = current_user.id
  end
  def create
    @ticket = Ticket.new(params[:ticket])
    @ticket.whodidit = current_user.id
    if @ticket.user_id != 0 && @ticket.team_id != 0
      flash[:alert] = "You cannot assign a ticket to both a team and a user!"
      render action: "new"
    else
    respond_to do |format|
      if @ticket.save
        TicketMailer.ticket_creation(@ticket).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to @ticket, notice: 'Ticket was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @ticket, status: :created, location: @ticket }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @ticket.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
    end
  end
  def update
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
    if (params[:user_id] != 0 && params[:team_id] != 0)
       flash[:alert] = "You cannot assign a ticket to both a team and a user!"
       render action: "edit"
    else
    respond_to do |format|
      if @ticket.update_attributes(params[:ticket])
        TicketMailer.ticket_update(@ticket).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to @ticket, notice: 'Ticket was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @ticket.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
    end
  end
  def destroy
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
    @ticket.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tickets_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
  def index
    @tickets = Ticket.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10, :order => 'id DESC'
  end
end
```

Here is my model:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :comments
  has_paper_trail
  attr_accessible :attachment, :subject, :content, :user_id, :department_id, :status, :priority, :shop_id, :order_id, :team_id, :whodunnit
  has_attached_file :attachment
  validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, {:content_type => %w(image/jpeg image/jpg image/png application/pdf application/msword application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document)}
  def self.receive_mail(message)
   id = message.subject[/(\d+)$/, 1]
   if id.present? && Ticket.exists?(id)
     Ticket.update(id, content: message.body.decoded, user_id:11)
   else
     Ticket.create subject: message.subject, content: message.body.decoded, department_id: 2, :incoming_email => message.from.first
   end
 end
end
```

Comment: `params[:user_id].to_i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to show us your controller to be able to answer that question fully. However I'd say this kind of logic is model-specific and has little to do with the controller. You need to move that logic into a validator method within your model. If the model isn't valid when it comes time to save (create/update) then the issue will bubble up into your controller anyway. Please post your model and controller scripts so I can show you the best way to modify them to get you what you want. When you do so, I'll update my answer.

EDIT:

Suffice it to say, the logic for denying the save was moved into the model and utilized with activerecord validations. Now, regardless of whether or not you're creating or updating, the same bit of logic will be run when the instance tries to save.

Your Class Definition:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :comments
  has_paper_trail
  attr_accessible :attachment, :subject, :content, :user_id, :department_id, :status, :priority, :shop_id, :order_id, :team_id, :whodunnit
  has_attached_file :attachment
  validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, {:content_type => %w(image/jpeg image/jpg image/png application/pdf application/msword application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document)}
  validate :check_ticket

  def self.receive_mail(message)
    id = message.subject[/(\d+)$/, 1]
    if id.present? && Ticket.exists?(id)
      Ticket.update(id, content: message.body.decoded, user_id:11)
    else
      Ticket.create subject: message.subject, content: message.body.decoded, department_id: 2, :incoming_email => message.from.first
    end
  end

private

  def check_ticket
    # The logic here is semantically confusing for me, as to why user_id and team_id being 0 means that you've assigned a ticket to both team and user, but I'm sure you have your reasons.
    user_id != 0 && team_id != 0 and errors.add(:base, 'You cannot assign a ticket to both a team and a user!')
  end
end
```

Your Controller:

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def create
    @ticket = Ticket.new(params[:ticket])
    @ticket.whodidit = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @ticket.save
        TicketMailer.ticket_creation(@ticket).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to @ticket, notice: 'Ticket was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @ticket, status: :created, location: @ticket }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @ticket.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @ticket.update_attributes(params[:ticket])
        TicketMailer.ticket_update(@ticket).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to @ticket, notice: 'Ticket was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @ticket.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: added the controller and model

Comment: Thanks! ... its working great. One thing though, the error is not showing up, any ideas why?

Comment: Off-hand I can't really say as I don't know the intricacies of your app. Check that the request parameters contain what you expect, and  you can start logging in your models to trace how the variables are used at different points along the process. Also, restart your entire app just to be sure there aren't any weird caching issues going on.

Comment: P.S. `user_id != 0 && team_id != 0` -- I'm checking that both are different than 0, not both to be 0. :)

Comment: As a last resort...you've thought about what happens when either of those are nil, yes? (i.e., is nil functionally the same as 0? If so, you've got a potential issue). At the very least, write a log message inside the validate method to see if it's being called at all.

Comment: Good thinking! I added this `def check_assigne
   user_id = 0 && team_id = 0 and errors.add(:base, 'You must assign the ticket to either a team or a user!')
 end`